# How to remove /web from url added with htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, symfony, mod-rewrite

I have added the following code to my `htaccess` file to redirect automatically the http URLs to https:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?domaine\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.domaine.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L,NE]
```

My problem is that I have a `/web` added automatically that I can't remove.

I use symfony2.7

Answer (score 1):

your vhost should be pointing INTO the /web directory,   not your symfony project folder

Answer (score 0):

You  don't  remove  it  . All traffic should go to that web folder.

You have 2 options :

1. As it was said change, vhost
2. Use symbolic link:
   install/move symfony somwhere above   and make  symbolic  link  from  symfony/web to your folder where domain is pointing.